# Bitbucket Pages: Are Custom Domain Name and Alternative Root Folder supported?

Tags: bitbucket

Is any of the following possible through Bitbucket Pages?

- use my own domain name instead of the default one. In particular, I want `USER.com` to point to `USER.bitbucket.io`. Redirect is not an option for me.
- set a root folder other than `/`. In particular, I want to set `/public` as the default folder of my `USER.bitbucket.io` project. Again, redirect is not an option for me.